# JS get file previously downloaded by the browser

Tags: javascript, web

Is there a way for JS to get a file from memory, Instead of making an http call every time the file is required?
I am trying to get a json file that is already loaded by an external library, when I make my request the browser makes an http call, it doesn't matter if I use fetch or xhr to make the call..
[image]

Comment: It will use the cache if it can.

Comment: This is handled by the caching headers.  Your browser will generally follow what the headers say.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Caching